# Esri Dashboard Serial Chart - Date axis only shows full labels

Tags: chart, dashboard

I have a table of dates and data in Portal. The dates are in date format and I configured the date to be the mm/dd/yyyy format in Pro.

I want to make a serial chart but the dates are not showing as I would like them to.

Unless I toggle Parse Dates it presents each day's label like this:

[image]

> Mon Sep 20 1929 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)

I've tried this using a different data set and have experienced the same result.

This didn't do this previously and I'm not sure why it is doing it now.